# "href" from tag_name("a") throws exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can get the links by tag_name but can't extract href from "a".

```
links = scroll_box.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
names = [name.get_attribute('href') for name in links if '.com/' in name.get_attribute('href')]
```

Second line of code throwing the below mentioned exception.

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: Does "Links" contain other than '.com/' type values? can you post the actual url? i would suggest to find the links using more specific locators like class, name etc..

Comment: Actually, I am working on instagram "follower/following" list data extraction. And I think there are other links as well in the "links". I can't specify "class" because it keeps changing for instagram website.

Answer (score 0):

You get all links and some of them changes while trying to get hrefs and this is a reason for `StaleElementReferenceException`. You can try to wait for links with required href.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

names = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href$=".com/"]')))]
```

In example above, links getted by `a[href$=".com/"]` from all page, not as `scroll_box` children. If you want to use `scroll_box`, modify locator to be as `scroll_box_selector a[href$=".com/"]` or use custom wait or implement custom `expected_conditions`

Comment: I have to use scroll_box because I want to extract the information of scroll_box only. I am working with instagram website and extracting followers/following list.

Comment: share html of the scroll box